# NetBeans 8.1 doesn't show maven src/it/resources node on Projects tab

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I use maven and netbeans. I have maven project (MyProject) and I have the following nodes on Projects tab:

MyProject:

- Source Packages (src/main/java)
- Other Sources (src/main/* except src/main/java)
- Test Packages (src/test/java)
- Other Test Sources (src/test/* except src/test/java)
- Generated Test Sources (src/it/java)

However, there is no node for src/it/resources what makes me always switch to Files Tab. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: What has this got to do with Eclipse?

Comment: I experienced sometimes the same: some maven standard direcory layout folder isn't created by NB on project creation. But once added in Files view it always appears in the Project view. You have a folder `src/main/resources` ? In my NB 8.1 it appears below `Other Sources`.

Comment: @PeterMmm Yes, I have. All the folders I have I listed in my question.

Comment: `src/it/resources` isn`t a folder from the [maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (I hope) will be solved when [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2470) is resolved. So, vote for it, if you need it.